# I wrote a little code but something might be wrong

Tags: python, list, random, numbers

The goal of this code is to generate a little list of 6 random numbers from 1 to 60, erase any repeated item and sort it, but I think something may be wrong because sometimes I execute this code and nothing happens, probably when a repeated number is drawn.

This is one of my first codes, so I'm thankful for any pointers.

```py
import random

a = []

while len(a) < 6 or len(a) != len(set(a)):
    a.append(random.randint(1, 60))

if len(a) > 6:
    a = set(a)

a.sort()

print(a)
```

Comment: Python has a lot of functionality already. Your entire program can be replaced by `a = sorted(random.sample(range(1,61),6))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You correctly identified the issue. The problem is indeed when a repeated number is chosen.

Once you generate a random number, you never delete it. So once a repeated number happens to be added to `a`, `len(a)` never equals `len(set(a))`, as `set(a)` will always be at least one element shorter, no matter how many numbers you add to it. This means your `while` loop will never terminate.

The solution to this is to realise that you don’t care about the length of `a`, only about the length of `set(a)`, since you don’t care how many numbers are added to `a` before you get 6 unique ones. So, all you need to check as the condition for you `while` loop is `len(set(a)) < 6`. Note that this allows you to remove the check right after the `while` loop. Finally, note that sets are unordered, and `a.sort()` will raise an error. If you really want it sorted, call the `sorted` function on it. Hope this helps!